# Change display when containing div changes size using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following scenario is my html page:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
</div>
```

If myDiv is less than some width X, then show A & B vertically. Else show A and B horizontally.
How can I achieve this in Bootstrap?

Comment: Do you have custom width or the `standard` one that are defined in `bootstrap`

Comment: standard (defined in bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

use [flex-direction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/) to switch between `row` and `column`. I've taken width as per standard define in [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/).

You can also switch not only in `row` or `column`, instead you can also use `row-reverse` and `column-reverse`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="myDiv" class="d-flex flex-sm-column flex-md-row flex-lg-column">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
</div>
```